# Invalid user when sending emails

Tags: email, postfix, courier

I have a Ubuntu server with Postfix and Courier (both appear to be running fine). We used to have a control panel provided by our host but after upgrading the server it's no longer available. But now all of our emails are bouncing.

We host several domains and several email addresses per domain. When I send email to e.g. `scott@example.com` it returns a failure notice:

> The mail system
>   <scott@example.com>: user unknown. Command output: Invalid user specified.

`scott@example.com` is not an actual user but between Postfix and Courier I think I traced where it comes from. The virtual domains file `/etc/postfix/virtual` shows lines like this for each email address (first column should be the email address, second column the user):

```
scott@example.com    scott@example.com
```

Now in the folder `/etc/courier/userdb/` there are files for each domain on the server. Inside these appear to be "virtual users" that correspond to the emails addresses set up. In the `example.com` folder is this:

```
scott@example.com       uid=1000|gid=1001|home=/home/example/example.com/system/mail/users/scott|mail=/home/example/example.com/system/mail/users/scott/Maildir|gecos=scott|systempw=$1$M0USmU7K$2f/KbNOLOdVqp.Ra4gKXR/
```

(The `example` in `/home/example/` is just a common user that "owns" several sites.)

My knowledge of Courier is almost non-existent but at a glance it seems like everything is set up. *Is there a missing link somewhere between Postfix and Courier? What methods are there to diagnose why the mail isn't working?*

Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the package `courier-authlib` or `courier-authlib-<Your source>` installed.

Comment: Yes, I do have courier-authlib installed.